# NativeScript layout expand image to fill screen while keeping button snapped to bottom

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-layout

Please code and images below.
I'm trying to expand the image as much as possible but retain the price and the *"Add to Cart"* button must be snapped to the bottom of the screen.

On the image XML attributes, when I try `stretch="none"` the image is too small.

When I try `stretch="aspectFit"` it expands but cuts off the price.

Ideally the price needs to be fixed above *"Add to Cart"* but I just can't get that right either.

By hook or crook I managed to get *"Add to Cart"* to stick to the bottom by using `row=1` and `row=2` instead of `row=0` and `row=1`.

But now the problem is I can't get that image to expand properly and not overwrite the price.

I'm open to I'm doing this totally wrong and BTW I have read all the docs and Google this to death. It took me three hours to align that button to the bottom of the screen. I generally prefer math problems.

```xml
<GridLayout rows="auto, *, auto">
      <StackLayout row="1">
        <Label :text="product.title" />
        <Image
          :src="getImage"
          loadMode="async"
          stretch="none"
          horizontalAlignment="center"
          class="m-t-10 m-b-10"
        />
        <Label :text="getPrice" horizontalAlignment="center" />
      </StackLayout>
      <GridLayout row="2">
        <Button @tap="addProductToCart(product)" text="Add to Cart" class="-outline -rounded-sm"></Button>
      </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

**Image 1 (with `stretch="none"` the image is too small and the price alignment incorrect)**

[image: This image is too small]

**Image 2 (with `stretch="aspectFill"` the image is too big and the price has been overwritten)**

[image: This image is too big]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` in the `GridLayout` means that it will take up the remaining space available, where as `auto` will take up the space required for the child.

If you move the `Label` that contains the price out of the `StackLayout` on row 1, and put it in its own row, similar to the checkout button, that should make the image be able to expand as much as possible up to where the price label is.

```html
<GridLayout rows="auto, *, auto, auto">
      <StackLayout row="1">
        <Label :text="product.title" />
        <Image
          :src="getImage"
          loadMode="async"
          stretch="aspectFit"
          horizontalAlignment="center"
          class="m-t-10 m-b-10"
        />
      </StackLayout>
        <Label row="2" :text="getPrice" horizontalAlignment="center" />
      <GridLayout row="3">
        <Button @tap="addProductToCart(product)" text="Add to Cart" class="-outline -rounded-sm"></Button>
      </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Brilliant it works! Just as I was working on that darn screen the notification came through. Thanks!